# How To use Contains in left outer Join Linq

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-sql

I have This Query

```
          from Room in PMSdb.Room_Tbl
                join Res in PMSdb.Reservation_Tbl on
                Room.Room_ID equals Res.Room_ID
                into ej
                from Res in ej.DefaultIfEmpty() 
                join Feature in PMSdb.Room_Features_Tbl on
                Room.Room_Features.Split(',').Contains(Feature.Room_Features_ID.ToString())
                into FE
                from Feature in FE.DefaultIfEmpty()
                  select new
                              {
                                  Room = Room.Room_Number,
                                  Room_type = RoomType.Room_Type_Code
                                  Feature =Feature.Feature_Name}
```

I need to do this
`Room.Room_Features.Split(',').Contains(Feature.Room_Features_ID.ToString())` but it refuse 
How can I do Something like this ?

Comment: So `Room_Features` is a comma separated list of features? If so, the short answer is 'don't do that'. You should instead have a `RoomFeatures` table which has two columns (Room_ID and Feature_ID) so that you can have a many to many relationship between Room and Feature.

Comment: @GertArnold How can I create a variable First as you said? because I don't have it , it gets dynamically

Comment: @mjwills Error in compilation `Error 1 Expected contextual keyword 'equals' 
`

Comment: See the `Room.Room_ID equals Res.Room_ID` line - that is what is expected after `join`...`on`. It is complaining that `Room.Room_Features.Split(',').Contains(Feature.Room_Features_ID.ToString())` doesn't provide the expected `equals`.

Comment: [tag:linq-to-sql] / [tag:entity-framework] - Which one is it?

Comment: Entity-framework

Comment: @mjwills I know but how can I solve it with the same logic

Comment: Where are your Navigation Properties?  Can you show us your model?  Andy why is Room.Room_Features a delimited string instead of a Navigation Property.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft `Room_Features ` is a string with format `1,5,8` which are the ID's of Room_Feature_Tbl

Comment: Yes, but why?  That's a terrible design.  RoomFeatures should be a separate table.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft Yes I Know that , I contacted the Database Designer but he refused to create a separate table as a composite, So I need a way to do it as its design

Comment: You'll probably need to just fetch the data to the client and run String.Split there, and perform the rest of the logic on the client.

Answer (score 0):

You should really look into normalizing that data using a junction table, comma-separated fields are a hallmark of bad database design.

That being said, the issue is that Entity Framework can't translate `string.Split()` to a SQL query.

If your data is stored as `,val1,val2,,val3,` (so prefixed and suffixed with a comma, and commas aren't valid values), you could resort to a `string.Contains`, which *can* be translated to SQL:

```
Room.Room_Features.Contains($",{Feature.Room_Features_ID},")
```

Comment: The OP probably has no option on changing an existing database so you recommendation is useless.

Answer (score -3):

How about this :

```
(from Room in PMSdb.Room_Tbl
            join Res in PMSdb.Reservation_Tbl on
            Room.Room_ID equals Res.Room_ID
            into ej
            from Res in ej.DefaultIfEmpty()
            select new { room = Room, res = Res)
            .Where(x => x.Res == null)
            .Select(x => new {
                             Room = x.room.Room_Number,
                             Room_type = x.room.Room_Type_Code,
                             Features = x.room.Room_Features.Split(new char[] {','})
                                .Select(y => PMSdb.Room_Features_Tbl.Where(z => z.Room_Features_ID.ToString() == y.Trim()).FirstOrDefault())
                                .ToList() 
            }).ToList();
```

Comment: What happened to the `Contains`? This is logically different. And EF6 wouldn't accept `String.Split`. Unfortunately, OP doesn't tell which ORM they're actually using.

Comment: @JdWeng where is the Room_Feature table ?I want to select from it

Comment: Isn't it part of : Room in PMSdb.Room_Tbl?

Comment: No, `Room_Features` is a string with format `1,5,8` which are the ID's of Room_Feature_Tb

Comment: Instead of answering with "try this [code block]", try explaining what problem the OP has, what you changed to circumvent that problem and how that actually solves said problem.

Comment: There was no issue.  I just didn't include all the required properties.

Comment: @CodeCaster is right. Answers that just offer code with no explanation, are far less useful than answers that explain and inform.

Comment: Experts do not need full explanations.  It is obvious here the person knew how to use linq, but was having syntax issues.

Comment: Everyone benefits from an explanation. Read [my answer in "What should a minimal answer contain?"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/298811/266143). We don't post answers just for the OP, but for everyone who reads the Q&A after them. If all answers were in the form you usually use, we'd have a site full of "try this [code block]" answers, and what would a Googler then have to do? Copy-paste the code from all answers? Read every line of code to try and guess what you were thinking when you wrote it? What if you were wrong in your assumptions or implementation? @David and I told you this often.